# Azure Service Fabric automatic upgrade

Tags: azure, upgrade, azure-service-fabric

When cluster is set on automatic upgrade mode The upgrade does not start even though there is a new version of the cluster. As it is said in documentation "You can set your cluster to receive automatic fabric upgrades as they are released by Microsoft" is it mean that upgrade will be done after end of support of current version ?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic updates have been paused during the Covid crisis.

> Due to the current COVID-19 crisis, and taking into consideration the
> challenges faced by our customers, we are making 7.1 available through
> the manual upgrade path, but clusters set to automatic upgrade will
> not automatically receive the upgrade at this time. Automatic upgrades
> will be paused until further notice to ensure that customers can apply
> upgrades when most appropriate for them, to avoid unexpected
> disruptions.

More info [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-service-fabric/azure-service-fabric-7-1-release/ba-p/1311373) and [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-service-fabric/azure-service-fabric-7-1-release/ba-p/1311373).